# Show only coordinates instead of full address in destination on google maps direction api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i am using google maps javacscript api for direction. May i know how can i show on coordinates in destination instead of full address on the direction panel?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the start and end location lat lng inside the legs of the Google Directions API Response

```
         "legs" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "9.7 mi",
              "value" : 15653
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "25 mins",
              "value" : 1480
           },
           "end_address" : "1 MetLife Stadium Dr, East Rutherford, NJ 07073, USA",
           "end_location" : {
              "lat" : 40.814505,
              "lng" : -74.07272910000002
           },
           "start_address" : "75 Ninth Ave, New York, NY 10011, USA",
           "start_location" : {
              "lat" : 40.7428759,
              "lng" : -74.00584719999999
           }]
```

See this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) for more details